# How can I access of websocket using MIT App Inventor?

Tags: android, websocket

Before asking my specific question my overall objective (in case there is a better way to do it) is to log data from a particulate matter sensor (PMS) with GPS co-ordinates on my ride to/from work to see how bad the air on my commute is.

So far I have the PMS connected to a raspberry pi, and am recording values from it using a python script.

I'm recording all these logged values to to a `log.txt` file following the process outlined here: https://www.perrygeo.com/raspberry-pi-real-time-sensor-plots-with-websocketd.html

I've then set-up a websocket (using `websocketd`) from the pi, which I can access from my computer. This just spits out a current time-stamp, and the particulate matter reading I'm interested in (again following tutorial linked above).

My question is how to access the data from this websocket in an Android App - ideally using MIT App Inventor 2 (as I'm a newb in Android). My google-fu has failed me on this one.

I'm also happy to be told that a websocket is not the best way to do it - I could serve up a JSON file on a webpage instead and parse that from the android app if that'd be easier, but had thought a websocket would be better/faster.

Having done a bit more research there is an extended discussion on this here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ai4a/pL4bHmJKnH0
It's suggested that I might be able to use a socket rather than a web-socket - I'd also be happy to do that.

Comment: Added additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems to do anything beyond the basics in MIT App Inventor 2 you need to add "extensions" which is what I was missing from my google search terms.

Specifically the following extension did exactly what I was needing - hope it's of help to other people who stumble upon this question (including me in the future!):

https://community.appybuilder.com/t/websocket-client-extension/1761

Finally I noticed that using the `websocketURI` with the host-name of the server machine (in my case `raspberrypi` did NOT work - I had to use the IP address. If anyone know why that might be and how to make the host-name discoverable on android please let me know!